# Symbol’s function definition is void: org-pdfview-open, pdf-tools are not working

Tags: pdf, pdf-tools

since some time I have encountered a problem with opening pdf links with pdf-tools.
I am using doom-emacs and have just the line

```
(add-to-list 'org-file-apps '("\\.pdf\\'" . org-pdfview-open))
```

to select the viewer in my config.
Previously all worked well. Now for some reason I can open pdfs with `counsel-find-file` or other commands. But if I press enter on a pdf link I get

```
Symbol’s function definition is void: org-pdfview-open
```

I know it's hard to determine the error source without seeing everything in detail, but what could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that symbol `org-pdfview-open` does not point to a function. This, and the fact that piece of configuration used to work, means that the function definition disappeared from your system.

Not sure how that happened exactly: I don't think [`org-pdfview`](https://github.com/markus1189/org-pdfview) was in the core of a previous version of Emacs (thus, could've disappeared because of an update). Perhaps you were moving code around, or changed the configuration of your `load-path` so that the code can't be loaded anymore.

Note, however, that in the [org-pdfview's repository](https://github.com/markus1189/org-pdfview) the package is indicated as not maintained anymore. It also points to a fork called [org-pdftools](https://github.com/fuxialexander/org-pdftools) (which I see available on Melpa).

If you want to proceed using this one, it seems you'll have to use the function `org-pdftools-open` instead of `org-pdfview-open`.

I hope this helps

Comment: At least I am somewhat further with my problem.
When I try to use `(add-to-list 'org-file-apps '("\\.pdf\\'" . org-pdftools-open))`
I get a new error message I am not able to interpret:


`user-error: Please see Org News for version 9.0 about ‘org-file-apps’--Lisp error: org-pdftools-open`.

Comment: Seems like this https://orgmode.org/worg/org-release-notes.html#org59828f4 ?

Comment: This seems to be saying that the function, as of Org 9.0, must accept two arguments, a file and a link, but `org-pdftools-open` only accepts a file. Maybe you can define your own function that takes the extra link arg, and ignores it and just calls `org-pdftools-open` with the file... but I don't understand the details enough to know if that would work.

Comment: Please don't ask a question in a comment. If the answer has helped, upvote it, even if it has not solved the problem (if it has solved the problem, you should accept it of course). Then ask a *new* question for `org-pdftools`. Questions or answers in comments are not useful: you cannot search for them (and search is difficult enough even without that complication).