# org-pdftools-open doesn't work for opening pdf links in org mode

Tags: pdf, pdf-tools

Motivated by the question [Symbol’s function definition is void: org-pdfview-open, pdf-tools are not working](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/72188/symbol-s-function-definition-is-void-org-pdfview-open-pdf-tools-are-not-workin/72189#72189)
I would like to be able to open pdf-links in org-mode, which worked fine until a while ago.
So far we figured out, that I should use `org-pdftools-open` instead of `org-pdfview-open`.

When I try to use `(add-to-list 'org-file-apps '("\\.pdf\\'" . org-pdftools-open))` I get an error message: `user-error: Please see Org News for version 9.0 about ‘org-file-apps’--Lisp error: org-pdftools-open`.
My question now simply is - how I can get `org-pdftools-open` to work to open pdf links?
Just viewing the pdfs works fine however, only opening them via links produces an error.